# Rewrite powershell file comparison without loops or if statements

Tags: powershell, refactoring

What's the best way to rewrite the following powershell code that compares a list of two files, ensuring they have the same (or greater) file count, and that the second list contains every file in the first list:

```
$noNewFiles = $NewFiles.Count -ge $OldFiles.Count
foreach ($oldFile in $OldFiles){
    if (!$NewFiles.Contains($oldFile)) {
        return $false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PSv3+ syntax (`?` is a built-in alias for `Where-Object` cmdlet):

```
(Compare-Object $NewFiles $OldFiles | ? SideIndicator -eq '=>').Count -eq 0
```

More efficient PSv4+ alternative, using the `Where()` *method* (as suggested by Brian (the OP) himself):

```
(Compare-Object $NewFiles $OldFiles).Where-Object({ $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' }).Count -eq 0
```

By default, `Compare-Object` only returns *differences* between two sets and outputs objects whose `.SideIndicator` property indicates the set that an element is unique to:

Since string value `=>` indicates an element that is unique to the 2nd set (RHS), we can filter the differences down to elements unique to the 2nd set, so if their count is 0, the implication is that there are no elements unique to the 2nd set.

Side note:
How "sameness" (equality) is determined depends on the data type of the elements.
A pitfall is that instances of *reference types* are compared by their `.ToString()` values, which can result in disparate objects being considered equal. For instance, `Compare-Object @{ one=1 } @{ two=2 }` produces *no* output.

Comment: This may not work if the files in `$NewFiles` aren't in the same order as in `$OldFiles`. However, if you pre-sort both lists ... :)

Comment: Actually, no, in the code above, you can legally add a file, or even change the file's data, without changing its name, and it still passes the above code, the main purpose of the code is to test if no files are removed, and they are all the same name

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: No, the order doesn't matter (which is why I used the word _set_, as in the docs). It's only if you use the `-SyncWindow` that order comes into play. Try `Compare-Object 1, 2  2, 1`, for instance.